# How to use Union , Order By and Rownum?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, union, rownum

Requirement : I want to perform Union first. Then Order By and then select 1 row.

```
select * from v$version;

--Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0
```

Below is my table.

```
MyTable1

Amt | CreationDate
-----------------
100 |  01/01/2021
200 |  01/02/2021
50  |  10/01/2021
```

MyTable2

```
Amt | CreationDate
-----------------
100 |  01/01/2021
200 |  01/02/2021
50  |  10/01/2021

SELECT amt
  FROM (SELECT amt
        FROM MyTable1
        UNION
        SELECT amt
        FROM MyTable2
        ORDER BY CreationDate DESC)
 WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Error is : ORA-00904 : CreationDate invalid identifier

I have this query inside PL/SQL code.

Comment: There is no `cst_amt` in your table, so how can you `select` it? In any case: the error is caused by `order by`. You can order by a column that is not in the `select` clause, but only when the query doesn't have set-theoretic operations (like `UNION`). Include the creation date in the `select` clause of both members of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `order by` CreationDate, it needs to be part of your `select`

```
select amt
from (select amt, creationdate 
      from mytable
      union
      select cst_amt, creationdate 
      from mytable
      order by creationdate desc)
where rownum = 1;
```

Judging from your intention with the code, I think you could have just done

```
select greatest(max(amt), max(cst_amt))
from mytable
where cst_amt is not not and amt is not null;
```

Oracle 12c supports `fetch` clause, so you can tinker with that too.

Comment: The second version won't work, for example, if all `cst_amt` are `null`. Then the `max` is `null`, and then `greatest` will be `null` too, regardless of what the `amt` values are.

Comment: @mathguy You're right, what was I thinking